# How to make Github auto-sign new tags?

Tags: git, github, github-actions, gpg-signature

I need to make Github auto-sign newly created tags for Action Workflow releases.

Here is my repo releases:
https://github.com/tomay3000/mingw-builds-binaries/releases

As you can see, the first (manually created) release was auto-signed, but not the second one that I also created manually from Github it self and let the Github Action Workflow triger the build process and upload the release artifact automatically.

The annoying thing is that the tag is not signed as the first one.

What should I do in this case? Can I add a signature to this tag release or I have to start over again?

**Note 1:** Issuing this command in my local Git terminal revealed the same GPG key used in the first release:

```bash
Tomay@Tomay-PC MINGW64 /c/Dev/mingw-builds-binaries (main)
$ git config --global user.signingkey
4AEE18F83AFDEB23
```

**Note 2:** I did a hard reset to the last commit instead of a revert one. Could it be the cause!?

Comment: See https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/667 and its [comment](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/667#issuecomment-775277257). Also, see [About commit signature verification](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification).